# Guidelines on voting to close a re-opened question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, vote-to-close

I just saw a question on [how to have more fun at work](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/77486/3688), which I was about to vote to close, when I read the comments, and saw that it had been closed/re-opened.

Personally, I think closing it was the right move (for reason in my comment to it). But, given that it *was* re-opened, should I *not* vote to re-close, at least for a period of time? Or just vote as I think it deserves, regardless?

Comment: Well, there was an edit since you posted, so the question made it to the homepage and got two close votes already...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should vote as you think. So vote to close if that's what you think should be the correct response in this case.

However, if it looks like the post is going to yo-yo between states then raising here on meta or flagging for moderator attention is the right thing to do. Then it can be discussed and we (as moderators) can act on the result of that discussion.

In this case it was re-opened by a moderator, so we probably wouldn't override that unless the post gained a lot of flags.

Comment: Being the moderator that both closed it *and* reopened it... I think you should act as you think is best in this case. I thought the question had potential (and possibly still does if the right answer were to come along and with some clean up of the "you just can't have fun at work" answers), but it didn't really work out well. Judge it under the current guidelines as you would any other question.

Comment: @AnnaLear - I saw that, but thought you closed and reopend to clear the votes...

Comment: No. Apparently (according to my comments) I closed and then changed my mind on further thinking.

Comment: Well that'll teach me to read the comments next time...

Comment: @AnnaLear, although I realize that good answers have sometimes redeemed poor questions (as per the [does torture work?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/4500/4910) question - I just don't see *this* question as having "the right answer". How to have fun at work? Sure, an interesting subject for a discussion, but not really answerable with a single, obviously-right answer. But I did go with the advice from everyone, and voted to close it. We'll see if anyone else agrees with me. :)

Comment: @Cyclops For what it's worth, if it were posted today, I'd have closed it.

Comment: @AnnaLear My first instinct upon reading the title was to close the question too, but then I actually read the body of the question and see why you saw some value there. I feel with some re-writing it could pass for a decent question on a site about programmers, although I don't think it would pass in any form with P.SE's current guidelines

Comment: @Rachel It is certainly borderline. It's the kind of question that could be saved by a great thought-out answer.